# Can we have multiple subscribers for RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have the following superscription code in my c# console application to drain messages from RabbitMQ queue:

```
consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
consumer.Received += (o, e) =>
{
    //onMessageReceived()
};


consumer.Shutdown += (oo, oe) =>
{
    //Handle Subscribe event
};
_channel.BasicConsume(QueueName, false ,consumer);
```

I have two instances of this console application running to  simulate multiple subscribers situation. I am always reeving messages to te first subscriber and second one is always idle. Can we have multiple subscribers to the same queue on RabbitMQ queue?

Comment: Have you tried to send more messages then one consumer can handle? Try to fill up the queue and start the subscriber afterwords, and check what's happening to in your subscribers. You can have multiple subscribers to one single queue in RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can but if the console applications are consuming messages from the same queue, they are competing on each other. So the messages inside the queue will be consumed only by one of those.

If you want to have more subscribers that receive the same messages, you need to define a different queue per subscriber, bound to the exchange (where the messages are passing through) that should be *fanout* or *topic* (not *direct*).

More info [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html) and [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html)

Comment: What is the best way to delete those queues? how would one know if client has disconnected?